# Id attribute is missing at <ds:SignedInfo>

Tags: xades4j

We signing the XML with below code , but we missing ID attribute in many place like 
SignedInfo and Object Tags

Please help us to rectify the code.
...........
            XadesSigningProfile p = new XadesBesSigningProfile(kp)
            .withBasicSignatureOptionsProvider(new extentProvider())
            .withAlgorithmsProviderEx(new AlgProviderEx());
            XadesSigner signer = p.newSigner();

.........
DataObjectDesc obj1 = new DataObjectReference(refUri)
            .withTransform(new EnvelopedSignatureTransform())
            .withDataObjectFormat(new DataObjectFormatProperty("text/xml","" ).withDescription("contenido comprobante"));
.....
signer.sign(obj1 ,objContent);

Answer (score 0):

XAdEs4j handles the generation of the Ids automatically as needed for the internal references. All the required IDs should be added. Do you need to reference those elements externally?